# How to use a configurable schema name in Keycloak User Storage SPI / Quarkus

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, keycloak, quarkus

I am implementing a custom user storage provider which gets the user data from an external PostgreSQL database. Since I have several schemas I want to create 2 instances of that provider where I am using the schema name to query the database.

I am about to use [this](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/extension/user-storage-jpa) example which is using quarkus and JPA(Hibernate) to encapsulate the database access.

How can I set the schema (within UserEntity?) programmatically to achieve that.

Thanks and Regards
matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite obvious but sometimes one  does not to see the wood for the trees:

The config metadata has to be configured with and to be returned from the
`public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties()` Method within the `UserStorageProviderFactory`

Then the name of the datasource (persistent unit) e.g. my-user-store which must be filled when the instance of the Provider is created/configured. The name then can be passed to the constructor of the `UserStorageProvider` which then can initialize the entity manager with

`em = session.getProvider(JpaConnectionProvider.class, datasourceName).getEntityManager();`

Within quarkus.properties and persistence.xml all datasources that should be used are configured.
The schema is set with `quarkus.datasource.my-user-store.jdbc.new-connection-sql=SET search_path TO my-schema`